# Shrink/pin navigation bar with header image using media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've just started experimenting with media queries and I seem to have reached a stumbling block with what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a simple header/banner with a navigation bar directly underneath it that includes links to four separate pages.

I have a media query set up to change the size of my header when the page is resized beyond a certain width and the navigation bar resizes with it. The problem I have is that the navigation bar stays static and will not 'snap' with the resized image leaving some ugly blue space visible between the top of the nav bar and the header itself.

The page in question can be found at www.grantdoole.co.uk

How can I snap or pin the nav bar to avoid making the page look tacky when it's resized?

(P.S: It's only the header and nav bar that have media queries applied to the page at present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the fixed height from inner-head and from header, it will follow your image up as it shrinks :)

Comment: No worries Grant, CSS is full of these little things! Thanks for marking my answer.